# Update Set Multiple Columns in Both Where Clause and Set Clause PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I'd like to run a command of which would update rows given multiple criteria in both the where clause and the set clause in PostgreSQL.

This seemed to run okay in PostgreSQL 12, but I would like to confirm this is accurate, properly constructed, and usable.

Here is an example, from the python script:

```
f"UPDATE schema.table set date_of_interest = '{date}', total_collect_to_date = {collect} where report_date = '2020-09-30' and app_num = '{app}'"
```

Comment: What is `'{date}'` supposed to mean? Are you trying to use a Python.format() function? Without any arguments?

Comment: date is just an arbitrary date from a loop. Same with all other parameters enclosed in {}. This is using an F-string, not a .format()

Comment: There is no loop. Your question is unreadable in its current form.

Comment: Why does this matter? The question pertains to the use of multiple where and set clauses combined. You can simply fill in any date for {date}, numbers for {collect}, string for {app}. The question is identical